# Codeigniter changes with `count_all_results`

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, query-builder

So... it appears as if overnight, SOME-thing has changed with either the Codeigniter 4 framework or PHP in general, as my website is now down - and it seems to be centred around my call to a `count_all_results` query using QueryBuilder.

My Controller:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $model = new ShopModel();
        $foo = $model->foo;
        $bar = $model->bar;
        $data = [
            'foo' => $foo, 
            'bar' => $bar, 
            'first' => $model->where(['availability' => 'in stock', 'shop.sale_price < price', 'shop.sku !=' => ''])->orderBy('round(((price - shop.sale_price) / price) * 100) DESC')->first() , 
            'count_all_results' => $model->countAllResults() , 
        ];
        $data['foo']['uri']['path']['controller'] = 'shop';
        echo view('default', $data);
    }
```

Logging onto my home page I'm getting the following error:

```
Undefined variable $count_all_results
```

I've played around with this, and removed the first instance of the error, and the code is fine again... until the next instance of calling `count_all_results` again.

I haven't altered or changed my code itself - this error has just 'appeared' all of a sudden! Has this been depreciated in PHP? Am I missing something obvious? Is it just a bug?

Any insight or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using this line of code
$data['foo']['uri']['path']['controller'] = 'shop';

Try commenting on this and run again.